# Reading input from text file and storing the output

Tags: function, validation, python-3.x, file-io

I have a function created for validating ISBN 10. It works well enough if the input is from the user. That's not enough, I want input from text file and store the output in text file.

```
    print("ISBN-Validation Program")
    isbn = input("Enter isbn: ")

    def stripDashes(isbn):
        sisbn = isbn.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").upper();

        return checkFormat(sisbn)

    def checkFormat(isbn):
        if len(isbn) == 10 and isbn[:9].isdigit()\
           and (isbn[-1] == "x" or isbn[-1] == "X" or isbn[-1].isdigit()):
            return isValiDisbn(isbn)
        else:
            print("ISBN is not properly formatted.")

    def isValiDisbn(isbn):
        if (isbn[-1] == "x" or isbn[-1] == "X"):
            total = int(isbn[0])*10 + int(isbn[1])*9 + int(isbn[2])*8\
                + int(isbn[3])*7 + int(isbn[4])*6 + int(isbn[5])*5\
                + int(isbn[6])*4 + int(isbn[7])*3 + int(isbn[8])*2 + 10
        else:
            total = int(isbn[0])*10 + int(isbn[1])*9 + int(isbn[2])*8\
                + int(isbn[3])*7 + int(isbn[4])*6 + int(isbn[5])*5\
                + int(isbn[6])*4 + int(isbn[7])*3 + int(isbn[8])*2 + int(isbn[9])

        if total % 11 == 0:
            print("The number is valid.")
        else:
            print("The number is not valid.")

    stripDashes(isbn)
```

The above function works for user input, I guess my code for the calling function and printing in text file is wrong somewhere.

```
    def main():
        inFile = open("isbn.txt", "r")
        outFile = open("isbnOut.txt", "a")

        for line in open("isbn.txt", "r"):
            isbns = line.split()
            for isbn in isbns: 
                if checkFormat(isbn) == False:
                    outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nISBN is not properly formatted.\n")
                if isValiDisbn(isbn) == True:
                    outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nThe number is valid.\n")
                if isValiDisbn(isbn) == False:
                    outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nThe number is not valid.\n")

        inFile.close()
        outFile.close()

    def stripDashes(isbn):
        sisbn = isbn.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").upper();

        return checkFormat(sisbn)

    def checkFormat(isbn):
        if len(isbn) == 10 and isbn[:9].isdigit() and (isbn[-1] == "x" or isbn[-1] == "X" or isbn[-1].isdigit()) == True:
            return isValiDisbn(isbn)
        else:
            return False
            #print("ISBN is not properly formatted.")

    def isValiDisbn(isbn):
        if (isbn[-1] == "x" or isbn[-1] == "X"):
            total = int(isbn[0])*10 + int(isbn[1])*9 + int(isbn[2])*8 + int(isbn[3])*7\
                + int(isbn[4])*6 + int(isbn[5])*5 + int(isbn[6])*4 + int(isbn[7])*3\
                + int(isbn[8])*2 + 10
        else:
            total = int(isbn[0])*10 + int(isbn[1])*9 + int(isbn[2])*8 + int(isbn[3])*7\
                + int(isbn[4])*6 + int(isbn[5])*5 + int(isbn[6])*4 + int(isbn[7])*3\
                + int(isbn[8])*2 + int(isbn[9])

        if total % 11 == 0:
            return True
            #print("The number is valid.")
        else:
            return False
            #print("The number is not valid.")

    main()
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here and help me to get through this?

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem, but you should not be calling `open("isbn.txt", "r")` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you forget to call `stripDashes`, so the ISBN is fed into `int` in the form `0-306-40615-2` instead of as `0306406152`

```
def stripDashes(isbn):
    sisbn = isbn.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").upper();

    return sisbn
```

And as part of your loop, do:

```
def main():
    inFile = open("isbn.txt", "r")
    outFile = open("isbnOut.txt", "a")

    for line in open("isbn.txt", "r"):
        isbns = line.split()
        for isbn in isbns:
            stripped_isbn = stripDashes(isbn)
            if checkFormat(stripped_isbn) == False:
                outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nISBN is not properly formatted.\n")
            if isValiDisbn(stripped_isbn) == True:
                outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nThe number is valid.\n")
            if isValiDisbn(stripped_isbn) == False:
                outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nThe number is not valid.\n")
```

It works fine:

```
$ cat isbn.txt 
0-306-40615-2
$ python isbn.py 
$ cat isbnOut.txt 
0306406152
The number is valid.
```

Other things to note:

- You open the in-file as `inFile = open("isbn.txt", "r")`, but then reopen it in the loop `for line in open("isbn.txt", "r"):`. Just use your open file like `for line in inFile:` or remove the first opening line.
- Your code that does the out-file writing is broken.

  ```
  if checkFormat(isbn) == False:
      outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nISBN is not properly formatted.\n")
  if isValiDisbn(isbn) == True:
      outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nThe number is valid.\n")
  if isValiDisbn(isbn) == False:
      outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nThe number is not valid.\n")
  ```

  If `checkFormat` return `False`, it will still check the ISBN for validity, so an `elif` should be used for the following lines. `isValiDisbn(isbn) == False` is also not needed, as it calls `isValiDisbn` twice, and compares it to `False` (just use `not`), so just use an `else`:

  ```
  if checkFormat(isbn) == False:
      outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nISBN is not properly formatted.\n")
  elif isValiDisbn(isbn) == True:
      outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nThe number is valid.\n")
  else:
      outFile.write(isbn.strip()+"\nThe number is not valid.\n")
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.  
But what should i do if i need the out put something like  
    0-471-58719-1  
    The number is not valid.  
    14-A123490-3  
    ISBN is not properly formatted.  
    0-32-108599-X  
    The number is valid.  

i mean with the dashes as original.  
right now i'm getting it without dashes.

Comment: @saroj If this works could you please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer, so that other users know this problem has been solved. Thanks!